# Why React's PureComponent is recommended to have all its children "pure"

Tags: reactjs

Having read the official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs), I've came across [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) regarding **PureComponent**:

> Furthermore, React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() skips prop
>   updates for the whole component subtree. Make sure all the children
>   components are also “pure”.

Why exactly does skipping props updates for the whole subtree means avoiding non-pure components? what would be the consequences of a non-pure component inside a PureComponent's component subtree (both in general and in the case when it's not designed/supposed to respond to props change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Pure Component for the same set of input props will give absolutely the same result, not just for itself but for the entire DOM tree. When you declare a `PureComponent`, not only do you need to think about props and `state`, but also `context`. `PureComponents` Block any context changes. Consider an example

```
<MyApp>      
 <Router>    // react-router.
  <App>   // A PureComponent
   <Switch>  // react-router Switch
     <Route ....>
   </Switch>
  </App>
 </Router>
</MyApp>
```

React-router’s Router will store current location in router props of context. And React-router’s Switch will read it back and choose a Route.But since `App` is a very pure component, and **will not** react to `context` change in Router, because it `not using` that values and should ignore them. And hence when you have a PureComponent in place, you should think about not only the component but also its nested children. So essentially you would also keep all your children Pure.

Comment: thanks for answering. What about the case when components in the children tree are not supposed (by design) to act upon props changes? Or is that what you were trying to say in your first sentence?

Comment: So In general, if the subComponents don't depend on context its probably doesn't matter if they are PureComponent or not, as their parent itself won't re-render. It only that if the Parent is a PureComponent the Children must be too as depicted by the example

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri are you sure about this? 90% of my components are Pure and when there is a children that needs to render it simply renders because the parent doesn't own the children render cycle.

Comment: @LeandroSoares, the child can re-render because of a state change, thats perfectly fine since in this case the shallowComparison for the component will return false and if no props for its children changes, the children will not re-render and hence even with PureComponent its fine.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i was talking about this "PureComponents Block any context changes".

Comment: So is the solution here to pass the context values to the children component and listen to them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Each prop should be immutable. It needs to easier debug.
For example. You put array of users via props. But, one of components do: user.name = value.
Children components may be much, and you will difficult understand, what is  component updates the user?